# JQuery Datatable initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm getting this error while trying to supply JSON into my DataTable:

> DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter 'a' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
[{
  "a": "asdsaddas",
  "b": "asdasda",
  "c": "0000000001",
  "d": "name"
}]
```

When user clicks button I'm generating and showing the table with an AJAX callback:

```js
$('#find_button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (validateAll()) {
    $("#myTable").DataTable({
      "lengthChange": false,
      "pageLength": 20,
      autoWidth: false,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      "dataSrc": "",
      "ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
        var $form = $("#my_form_id");
        var jsonData = getFormData($form, data.start, data.length);
        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "api",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
          dataType: "json"
        });

        request.then(function(response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));

          callback({
            data: [JSON.stringify(response.data)],
            recordsTotal: response.total,
            recordsFiltered: response.total
          })
        }, failCallback);
      },
      columns: [{
        "data": "a"
      }, {
        "data": "b"
      }, {
        "data": "c"
      }, {
        "data": "d"
      }],
      filter: false,
      info: false,
      ordering: false
    });

    $('#htmlTable').show();
  }
});
```

I've read a lot of related questions with same bug, but still cannot make it work in my case. Maybe there is problem that DataTable is initialized before it gets response from server?

Comment: Have you checked the link in the error? The diagnosis steps are quite clear: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4#Parameter-is-a-string. In short, you're providing values of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, yet you have a named column defined as `organizacjaPozytkuPublicznego` which has no matching value in the JSON.

Comment: Sorry i was changing the real values to these 'a', 'b' 'c' etc and forget to change in error message. Now is edited properly